# ArrayList. Доступ к элементу. Не всё так просто

Tags: java, массивы

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, как получение данных из листа. Казалось бы что всё просто, но вот не совсем. Вот смотрите:

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add("1");
a.add("2");
a.add("3");

ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<>();
b.add(a.toString());
String splitStr = b.get(0);
System.out.println(splitStr);
```

Получаю данные такого вида:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Так вот собственно вопрос: Как получить доступ к этим элементам? Получился двумерный массив. Но не пойму как добраться до него? Пробовал вот так:

```
for(String getSplit : splitStr.split("([),(])")){System.out.println("str   "+getSplit);}
```

Но остаются квадратные скобки.

```
str [1
str  2
str  3]
```

Т.е делаю что-то не так. Пробовал через regex

```
  Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("([),(])");
  Matcher mat = pat.matcher(splitStr);

  while(mat.find()) 
  {
    System.out.println("str "+mat.group());
  }
```

Получаю запятые. Есть ли стандартные методы какие-то? Что-бы не изобретать колесо.

В общем получилось вот так:

```
    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
    a.add("1");
    a.add("2");
    a.add("3");

    ArrayList<ArrayList> b = new ArrayList<>();
    b.add(a);

   for(int q =0; q < b.size(); q++ )
   {
       for(int t=0; t< a.size(); t++)

       {

       System.out.println( b.get(q).get(t));
       } 
   }
```

Всем спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Либо я вас не понял, либо вы сильно запутались. b - это не двумерный массив, это список строк. То что вы записали туда значение toString у другого списка не делает его двумерным массивом.

Comment: Как вариант сделать `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`

Comment: Если вы нашли решение самостоятельно, то опубликуйте его в [в виде ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (кнопка "Ответить на собственный вопрос"), а не давайте ответ в вопросе. Заголовок вопроса должен содержать краткую суть проблемы, а не художественные изыски.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может вот так будете использовать данную схему?

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arr2 = new ArrayList<>(); // один массив в другом массиве. 

ArrayList<String> arr1 = new ArrayList<>();

arr1.add("1");
arr1.add("2");
arr1.add("3");

arr2.add(arr1);

System.out.println(arr2.get(0).toString()); // будет [1, 2, 3]

for (String s : arr2.get(0)) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Вывод

```
[1, 2, 3]
1
2
3
```

Квадратные скобки остаются, потому что в таком виде представляются элементы списка и не только. Обычно используется `ClassName[element1 = value1, element2 = value2]` или  `ClassName[value1,value2]` , если в классе один тип данных, как в твоем случае.